# SQL Update code to move data from one cell to another

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code in visual basic to a sql server. Part of Code:

```
Comments = ReasonNotDone + ' " & Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString & "', ReasonNotDone = '' WHERE IsDone = 'False' OR IsDone IS NULL AND ActiveDate = '" & Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString & "'"
```

Is this code correct? The `Comments` cell is set to the date, but the data from `ReasonNotDone` is not added. The data from the `ReasonNotDone` is set to `''` though.
Could it be that the data from `ReasonNotDone` is set to `''` before it gets the value for `Comments` ?

Comment: Is there definitely data in ReasonNotDone (ie it's not NULL)? Could you perhaps send the full section of code to assist with finding the problem.

Comment: First of all when you say "code" what exactly do you meant to say: is it in SQL statement/store proc or in VB code. Because it will be totally different for each of those. If you have it in VB then as soon as you put single ' you commented out all what comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the SQL syntax errors which I post as a comments Man you have following

```
ReasonNotDone = '' WHERE IsDone = 'False' OR IsDone IS NULL AND ActiveDate = '" & Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString & "'"
```

and where exactly you planning to concatinate additional

```
 ReasonNotDone + **' " & Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString & "'**
```

your SQL will look at the end like this

```
 ... AND ActiveDate = '4/4/2014''4/4/2014'
```

it is messed up syntax completly.